# Trying to run a Ajax request from a checkout form in woocommerce via a custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I have a custom plugin with the following code

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "gift_card_redeem", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/plugin-folder/gift_card_redeem.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'gift_card_redeem', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'gift_card_redeem' );

}

add_action("wp_ajax_gift_card_redeem", "gift_card_redeem");

function gift_card_redeem(){

  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    error_log("test !empty");
    $result['type'] = "success";
    $result = json_encode($result);
    echo $result;
  }
  else {
    error_log("test else");
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
  }

  die();
}
```

and a js file in the plugin called gift_card_redeem.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".redeem_gift_card").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
      data: { action: "redeem_gift_card" },
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.type == "success") {
          jQuery("#test").html(response);
        } else {
          alert("something broke");
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

and my php and html on the form-checkout page is as follows

```
<?php
    $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=gift_card_redeem');
        echo '<a class="redeem_gift_card" href="' . $link . '" >test</a>';
    ?> 

    <h1 id="test">Test</h1>
```

I am getting a 400 bad request error for admin-ajax.php and I am not quite sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My action was wrong in the ajax request

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".redeem_gift_card").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
      data: { action: "gift_card_redeem" }, // not redeem_gift_card
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.type == "success") {
          jQuery("#test").html(response.type);
        } else {
          alert("something broke");
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```